# Xcode Units Tests can't find header file - #import <OpenGL/gl.h>

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, unit-testing, opengl

I'm using Xcode Unit Tests which import a file that tries to import the OpenGL headers like this:

```
#import <OpenGL/gl.h>
#import <OpenGL/glu.h>
#import <OpenGL/glext.h>
```

Unfortunately, it can't find these files. If I try to import them in the Unit Test files directly they are also not found.

In my actual app (both for iOS and Mac OS), everything works fine.

I've probably read all posts here and tried everything I found on Google, but no luck yet. Also full clean, rebuild, restart, etc. does not work.

I hope somebody has an idea.

EDIT: Some more things that I tried without any luck:

- Adding OpenGL Framework to the Test target
- Adding the location of the OpenGL Framework as a search path. I tried UserHeader Search path, framework search path and the regular header search path

Comment: Add the OpenGL framework to your unit test target.

Comment: I did, doesn't work.